# How to use named parameters in a TableAdapter query?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am configuring a dataset through the query wizard. I want to generate the parametrized query. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    Field1 = @field1
```

The data is being fetched from an Access 2007 database, where this query executes successfully. From code however, I am getting the error:

> Error in WHERE clause near '@'. Unable to parse query text.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I was telling aboutTableAdapter config wizard. By the way you can see the [query](http://i.imgur.com/MJ3IeBs.png) and [error](http://i.imgur.com/HBzvZJO.png") @Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access doesn't support named parameters and uses `?` instead of `@` (like SQL-Server).

So this  should work:

```
...
WHERE
    Field1 = ?
```

See also [How to: Create Parameterized TableAdapter Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When constructing a parameterized query, use the parameter notation specific to the database you are coding against.
>
> For example, Access and OleDb data sources use the question mark `'?'` to denote parameters, so the `WHERE` clause would look like this: `WHERE City = ?`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, @Tim Schmelter, It's working perfectly.