# Error in WHERE clause near '@'. Unable to parse query text C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, where-clause, tableadapter

I am trying to add a parameter to my table adapter in my C# project. When I add the @ to the where clause visual studio gives me an error. Here is my SQL statement:

```
select PO.PO_Num,
  PO.Supplier,
  PO.DateOrdered,
  PO.DateRequired,
  PO.Terms,
  PO.Freight,
  PO.FOB,
  POItems.PO_Num as Expr1,
  POItems.Quantity,
  POItems.Description,
  POItems.Item,
  POItems.Price,
  POItems.KeyNum
from PO,
  POItems
where PO.PO_Num = POItems.PO_Num
  and (PO.PO_Num = @PO_Num)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use a question mark instead of `@PO_Num`. What did you try? Did you search the web for the error message?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use named parameters in a TableAdapter query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270591/getting-error-while-configuring-the-fill-method-of-tableadapter-config-wizard).

Comment: @CodeCaster I can just add a ? instead of "at symbol" + parameter to create a parameter? And I tried what you see above, since I didn't know what else to try or do.

Comment: _"What have you tried"_ does not mean _"What code do you currently have that doesn't work"_, but it mean _"What have you tried to resolve the issue"_, hence my asking about you searching the web. Parameters for OLEDB are parsed in order, so just `?` will do.

Comment: @CodeCaster And this is not a duplicate question to the one that you posted. since I am not using access, and I am using SQL. I am also trying to use the "at symbol" to create a parameter, which SQL lets you do.

Comment: It **is** a duplicate. The error is not caused by Access, but by the data access the TableAdapter uses (most likely OLEDB in this case, given the error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the error I needed to change the where clause from this:

```
where PO.PO_Num = POItems.PO_Num and (PO.PO_Num = @PO_Num)
```

And add a question mark (?) in stead of the at symbol (@) like so:

```
where PO.PO_Num = POItems.PO_Num and (PO.PO_Num = ?)
```

After that I was able to execute the query, and Visual Studio 2010 didn't throw an error.

Comment: This worked in Visual Studio 2015 connecting to a PostgreSQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem when adding a table adapter and using a data source of .NET framework Data provider for oracle.  The two solutions of changing the where clause to use "@" and "?" didn't work for me.

Instead, I had to use the following:

```
where PO.PO_Num = POItems.PO_Num and (PO.PO_Num = :PO_Num)
```